# How can I replace the code without scrollIntoView and merge two useEffects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, frontend

When the page loads, the current month should be displayed in center.
Now this code works somehow, but the requirement is to not use two useEffects and scrollIntoView.

This is initial code.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const element = document.querySelector('button[data-active="true"]');
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      element?.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'auto',
        block: 'center',
        inline: 'center',
      });
    }, 300);
  
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timer);
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const element = document.querySelector('button[data-active="true"]');
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      element?.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth',
        block: 'nearest',
        inline: 'center',
      });
    }, 300);

    trackEvent('Click', 'Month Tab');
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timer);
    };
  }, [months, selectedMonth]);
```

Can someone please help me here.

Tried an alternative of scrollIntoView:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const element = document.querySelector('button[data-active="true"]');
  const container = document.documentElement; // Change this to the appropriate container element if needed
  const timer = setTimeout(() => {
    const elementRect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    const containerRect = container.getBoundingClientRect();

    const scrollOptions = {
      left: elementRect.left + elementRect.width / 2 - containerRect.width / 2,
      top: elementRect.top + elementRect.height / 2 - containerRect.height / 2,
      behavior: 'smooth',
    };

    container.scrollTo(scrollOptions);
  }, 300);

  trackEvent('Click', 'Month Tab');
  return () => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
  };
}, [months, selectedMonth]);
```

But this is not working and on page load the current month is not displaying and in center.

Tried the below code but then current month does not display in center of the page on page load.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const element = document.querySelector('button[data-active="true"]');
    const container = document.documentElement; // Change this to the appropriate container element if needed
    let scrollOptions;
  
    const scrollIfNeeded = () => {
      const elementRect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
      const containerRect = container.getBoundingClientRect();
  
      const shouldScroll =
        elementRect.left < containerRect.left ||
        elementRect.right > containerRect.right;
  
      scrollOptions = {
        behavior: shouldScroll ? 'auto' : 'smooth',
        left: elementRect.left + elementRect.width / 2 - containerRect.width / 2,
        top: elementRect.top + elementRect.height / 2 - containerRect.height / 2,
      };
  
      container.scrollTo(scrollOptions);
    };
  
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      scrollIfNeeded();
      trackEvent('Click', 'Month Tab');
    }, 300);
  
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      if (scrollOptions && scrollOptions.behavior === 'smooth') {
        container.scrollTo(scrollOptions);
      }
    };
  }, [months, selectedMonth]);
```

Comment: Can anyone help me here?